# How to add pulsing dot animation over image in HTML based on coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, css

I think it's worth noting that I am a beginner and honestly lost. Anyway so, my objective is that I am trying to place pulsing dot animation over an image.

The current code I have is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    #bg {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      /* Preserve aspet ratio */
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

  </style>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/52dLf1W.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
</body>

</html>
```

And I would like to add this pulsing animation based on coordinates

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #cfd9df;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .circle {
            background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
            border-radius: 50%;
            animation: pulse-red 1.9s infinite;
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
        }


        @keyframes pulse-red {
            0% {
                transform: scale(0.9);
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
            }
            
            80% {
                transform: scale(1);
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 11px rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
            }
            
            100% {
                transform: scale(0.9);
                box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
            }
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Right now, I have two files, but in the end I would like to have only one html file that contains all these.

Using the pulsing dot animation, I would like to make the current image like this `https://i.imgur.com/rsB0pBJ.jpg`. Using coordinate tracker, the coordinates of the dots in the image were ([1053, 567], [1164, 516], [1262, 512], [1122, 456]).

The problem is that how do I implement that? All the tutorials were just using `em` or pixels and I couldn't figure out how to use those coordinates.

*I need this to be responsive so depending on the browser size or screen size, it needs to scale back to where the actual dots needs to be.

Comment: How is your coordinate system defined ? What exactly does `[1053, 567]` mean ? What are the dimensions of your coordinate system container ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy So basically, I just used Mac screenshot (command shift 4) to see what the coordinates where haha, I guess it's not useful? Perhaps if there's a better way to handle this? you can click on the second picture link to see the dots

Comment: One way to handle this is to first define what your actual coordinate system is. Then when the image has rendered, you can get the height and width of the image according to screen size. Then you can use cartesian math to basically modify your older points into new points that fit inside your image bounds.

Comment: I think my answer here [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67422567/position-element-relative-to-responsive-scaling-image/67445691#67445691 is what you need.  The trick is to measure things to get percentage offsets and to calculate how much of the image is actually showing when you have it set to cover (i.e. some of it gets cropped).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an onClick function on your window to add it where you like:

Here

```js
function placeDiv(x_pos, y_pos) {
  var d = document.querySelector('.circle');
  d.style.position = "absolute";
  d.style.left = x_pos + 'px';
  d.style.top = y_pos + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  placeDiv(e.clientX, e.clientY);
});
```

```css
#bg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* Preserve aspet ratio */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: pulse-red 1.9s infinite;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

@keyframes pulse-red {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 1);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 11px rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 82, 82, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/52dLf1W.jpg" id="bg" alt="">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That was crazy fast. Awesome. I have edited your answer to fix the translate issue.

Comment: But still, I dont think this answers OP's question. His points are predefined I think.

Comment: Btw, @NisanthReddy it was fast because this was related to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67543158/12415287

Comment: Ah ok :). That explains it.

Comment: Wow awesome! What if I need 4 dots? How do I tweak this?

Comment: Here's one with an input field. By no means is it responsive, but this would get you started. https://jsfiddle.net/wpt7se5q/